# How can I concatenate a list of 2D numpy arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have a list of nested numpy arrays of shape (30,3). I tried to use numpy's `vstack`, `hstack` and `concatenate`, but I get an error: `ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly`

```
`[array([[[430, 110,  10],
    [ 62, 167,  10],
    [116, 136,  10],
    [341, 104,  10],
    [ 21, 116,  10],
    [371,  20,  10],
    [343, 197,  10],
    [ 59, 308,  10],
    [ 33,  23,  10],
    [215,  70,  10],
    [256,  73,  10],
    [ 94, 397,  10],
    [135, 251,  10],
    [202, 283,  10],
    [233, 313,  10],
    [319,  13,  10],
    [ 98, 273,  10],
    [261, 167,  10],
    [160, 296,   9],
    [137,  56,  10],
    [ 21, 320,  10],
    [ 77, 109,   9],
    [295, 356,  10],
    [178, 425,  10],
    [259,  35,   9],
    [319, 416,   9],
    [386, 331,   9],
    [319,  43,   9],
    [209, 409,   9],
    [115, 199,   9]]], dtype=uint16),` etc
```

I would like it to transform this into a normal list of lists, so getting rid of the `array` signs, just a plain list that I can easily manipulate.

Comment: What shape do you expect the output to be?

Comment: Can you post your code so that we use it as a base we iterate on ?

Comment: Verify the shape of ALL those arrays.  The one you show looks (1,30,3).

Comment: @hpaulj It is a list of numpy arrays of shape `(1,30,3)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a plain list without the `array` signs, use `<your_array>.tolist()` The `.tolist()` will convert it to a plain list which is easily manipulatable. I hope this helps you

Comment: I solved it by creating a list comprehension like this: `concat = [array.tolist() for array in cell_coordinates]`. `cell_coordinates`being the list of numpy arrays.Thank you!